# Conditional update column with PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Currently, I have to update some SQL that looks like this:

```
$varb = "";
if ($something) {
    $varb = ", colb='abc'";
}
mysql_query("update foo set cola='$vara'$varb where id='$id'");
```

Notice how `colb` is conditionally updated based on `$something`. I have to update it to use PDO, but I'm having trouble replicating the `$varb` part. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is what it would look like with PDO, but notice that `colb` is not conditionally updated like it is in the original:

```
$st = $db->prepare("update foo set cola=:vara, colb='abc' where id=:id")
```

Comment: can you post your PDO code you have so far so we have something to go on?

Comment: Are you always using a _static_ value for `colb` as in `'abc'`, or was that a variable value before?

Comment: This is still just a simple string concatenation if it's a static value, and a string concatenation plus an array append otherwise...

Comment: it is not always static, but i was hoping there was a concise way to do this conditionally in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is to do the decision logic in the query.

```
UPDATE ...
SET cola = :vara,
   colb = IF(:something, :varb, colb)
```

If `:something` evaluates to false, then you do the equivalent of `SET colb = colb`, which is essentially a null-op. It's a bit less efficient, since you have to send $something over to the DB, but it has the advantage of simplifying the query construction.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($something) {
    $foo = 'bar';
} else {
    $foo = null;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare(sprintf(
    'UPDATE foo
        SET cola = :vara %s
      WHERE id = :id',
    $foo ? ', colb = :varb' : null
));

$stmt->bindValue(':vara', ...);
if ($foo) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':varb', $foo);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Something along these lines.